Why am I losing internet connection on already connected devices, whenever another device connects to the router?
Laptop and other devices connected to the router lose the internet momentarily, between 3 to 30s, when I activate my cell phone's WiFi (or any other device's) to connect to the router. (It is almost as if all of their connections undergo a forced "restart" when any other device is connected).
This problem is especially severe with my secondary router (where the usual connecting time is high, it takes anything between 5-10s to 1-2 mins) so a reset in connections means waiting a long time.
How to solve this connection disabled problem when I activate my cell phone's WiFi to connect to the router?

Perhaps you need a better router?

@ChanganAuto Possibly yes. I'm a complete novice when it comes to this, so I don't know. But the problem is not just with my secondary (the old "bad") router. Since the problem exists with both routers, it seems there could be some issues with the settings or the signal itself, I don't know. I would be glad for any suggestions to troubleshoot this issue.

@John Ok, I will try it.

@Neeraj Kumar's please be as objective in your questions, comments about your particular situation do not need to be posted in the questions.

@Clamarc thanks for the advice.

I've had this issue when DHCP (IP address allocation) is managed by two routers on the same LAN.  Make sure the second router has DHCP turned off.  I've even seen where some Netgear routers send garbage DHCP expiry messages at 12 hours instead of 24 hours, causing all sessions to disconnect.
